# Python: Too many values to unpack (dictionary)

Tags: python, dictionary, unpack

I'm trying to add key-value pairs to a dictionary by pairing two and two lines from a text file. Why does this not work?

```
newdata = {}
os.chdir("//GOLLUM//tbg2//tbg2//forritGB")
f = open(filename)
for line1, line2 in f.readlines():
    newdata[line1] = line2
```

edit: The error I get is

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading all lines, and assigning the first line (a sequence) to two variables. This only works if the first line consists of 2 characters. Use the file as an iterator instead:

```
newdata = {}
os.chdir("//GOLLUM//tbg2//tbg2//forritGB")
with open(filename) as f:
    for line1 in f:
        newdata[line1.strip()] = next(f, '').strip()
```

Here `next()` reads the next line from the file.

The alternative would be to use a pair-wise recipe:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def pairwise(iterable):
    return izip_longest(*([iter(iterable)] * 2), '')

newdata = {}
os.chdir("//GOLLUM//tbg2//tbg2//forritGB")
with open(filename) as f:
    for line1, line2 in pairwise(f):
        newdata[line1.strip()] = line2.strip()
```

Note the `str.strip()` calls, to remove any extra whitespace (including the newline at the end of each line).

Answer (score 0):

```
newdata = {}
os.chdir("//GOLLUM//tbg2//tbg2//forritGB")
with open(filename) as f:
    for line1, line2 in zip(*[iter(f)]*2):
        newdata[line1] = line2
```

or

```
os.chdir("//GOLLUM//tbg2//tbg2//forritGB")
with open(filename) as f:
    newdata = dict(zip(*[iter(f)]*2))
```

Comment: Why read the whole file into memory? `.readlines()` is a memory hog here, just use `f` *directly* and have lines read using a buffer.